# Nginx reverse proxy static assets 404 not found

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using Nginx and reverse proxy, also Docker.

I have two Docker containers.

```
319f103c82e5        web_client_web_client   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   6 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp      web_client
7636ddaeae99        admin_web_admin         "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:6500->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7000->443/tcp   web_admin
```

This is my two containers. When I enter http://website.com, it goes to web_client_web_client container. When I enter http://website.com:6500, it goes to admin_web_admin container. This is the flow right now.

What I want is I don't want my admin users to type http://website.com:6500 to get to the admin page. I prefer them to type http://website.com/admin. So I decided to use proxy_pass which means, when accessing http://website.com/admin, it should proxy_pass to https://website.com:7000

So now, I am posting a Nginx config for web_client_web_client since it's the one which handles requests for port 80 and 433.

Here it is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name website.com;
    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    location /admin {
        proxy_pass https://website.com:7000/;
    }

    # I also tried
    #location /admin/ {
    #   proxy_pass https://website.com:7000/;
    #}

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.com;
    
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_types text/plain text/xml application/javascript text/css;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
    location / {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.(?!html) {
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2678400";
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

Now, what happens is, static files (css and js files are not loaded) and when inspecting from chrome,  request gets made as `https://website.com/static/css/app.597efb9d44f82f809fff1f026af2b728.css` instead of `https://website.com:7000/static/css/app.597efb9d44f82f809fff1f026af2b728.css`. So it says 404 not found. I am not sure why I cannot understand such a simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is not really with nginx but with how the 2 applications are setup. I don't have your code but this is what I can infer from your post:

In your pages you load the static content using absolute paths: /static/css/...
So even when you call your pages with /admin in front they will still try to load the static content from /static/

One solution is to use relative paths for your static content. Depending on how complex your application is this might require some work... You need to change the path to static files to something like "./static/css/..." and make sure your files still work. Then your setup in nginx will work because admin pages will try to load '/admin/static/...'

Another solution is to rename the 'static' folder in the admin app to something else and then proxypass that new path as well in your nginx config.

One last thing, your post mentions 2 ports: 6500 and 7000. I am assuming that is a mistake so can you correct it? Or did I understand wrong?

Comment: Yeap, 7000 and 6500 are by mistake. let's make it to be 7000. THe thing is I use vue.js projects. and I presume this might be because of this.  Also, I use webpack so after build, it generates its own js and css files. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: you can also setup webpack to generate files in a different location. Did you try my solutions at least?

Comment: in the admin app, in index.html, i changed href="/static/style.css" to href="./static/style.css" , but still, when accessing website.com/admin, it says style not found.

Comment: What exactly is it trying to fetch (what is the page that gives 404)?

Comment: I made it look like that it now makes request to website.com/admin/static/style.css, but the bad thing about this is that router gives me 404 not found page for content. but now style gets loaded. really funny.

Comment: At least one problem solved :) try now to curl your app from inside the container and make sure like that works. If it doesn't you need to check your webpack setup. If it does work try the other option with /admin/ in nginx